# Selecting items in the last row of a CSS grid based on class and data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I group `div` items by year in a CSS grid without specifying the year in the CSS? The year is included as a `data-group` attribute in every div. I want to pick the last `div`s of any year for `.year`, `.link` and `.title` and group them with a border.

I need to do something like below but it doesn't work at all. I need to group items by year without actually knowing what year it is.

```css
.year[data-group="unknown"]:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
          <div data-group="2018" class="year">2018</div>
          <div data-group="2018" class="link"><a href="#"></a></div>
          <div data-group="2018" class="title">Avengers: Infinity War <span>as Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow</span></div>

          <div data-group="2017" class="year">2017</div>
          <div data-group="2017" class="link"><a href="#"></a></div>
          <div data-group="2017" class="title">Ghost In The Shell <span>as Major Mira Killian / Motoko Kusanagi</span></div>

          <div data-group="2017" class="year">2017</div>
          <div data-group="2017" class="link"><a href="#"></a></div>
          <div data-group="2017" class="title">Thor: Ragnarok <span>as Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow (archive footage / uncredited)</span></div>

</div>
```

Comment: you want to have `bottom-border` under the `div.year` which unknown or under all related to that year

Comment: From what I can tell, It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe you could segment your grid out into flex-layout sections and style them?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done using CSS only, but as you tagged javascript I assume you are happy with a solution using js.

The difficulty in doing this is that we are not just looking for the last element with the `data-group` for that year - we are looking for *last data-group for **each class type** for each year*. Therefore we have to keep track of the classes *and* years that we have found.

**Based on the HTML you have provided**, the code below will find the last `year`, `link` and `title` classes for each year and add a CSS class with a border.

**What is it doing:**

1. Create a CSS class for the styling
2. Create an array to keep track of each year and class combination (e.g. 2017 .year, 2017 .link etc) - I've called this `processedDivs` in the code below
3. Get a list of all the elements with the `data-group` attribute
4. Loop through these *in reverse*... this means that the *first* elements of a particular type that we process in out loop are the actually the *last* in your data
5. Check if we have added this year and class to our processedDivs
6. if not, then this is the first time we have found this class and year, so add our CSS style

**Working Example:**

```js
/* 2. array to keep a record of the years and classes we have processed */
let processedDivs = new Array; 

/* 3. get all years in an array */
let allYears = document.querySelectorAll('[data-group]');

/* 4. loop through the Divs in reverse so we add the style to the first in our list*/
for (i = allYears.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Get the year and class name
    year = allYears[i].getAttribute('data-group');
    className = allYears[i].className;

    // 5. if we haven't added the CSS to this class for this year...
    if (processedDivs.indexOf(year+className) === -1) {
        processedDivs.push(year+className);           // add to the list
        allYears[i].classList.add("year-separator")  // add the CSS class
    }
}
```

```css
/* 1. our class to apply to the last "row" for each year */
.year-separator {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.grid { 

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 1fr;
}
.grid div {

}
```

```html
<div class="grid flex-row-container">
      <div data-group="2018" class="year">2018</div>
      <div data-group="2018" class="link"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div data-group="2018" class="title">Avengers: Infinity War <span>as Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow</span></div>

      <div data-group="2017" class="year">2017</div>
      <div data-group="2017" class="link"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div data-group="2017" class="title">Ghost In The Shell <span>as Major Mira Killian / Motoko Kusanagi</span></div>

      <div data-group="2017" class="year">2017</div>
      <div data-group="2017" class="link"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div data-group="2017" class="title">Thor: Ragnarok <span>as Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow (archive footage / uncredited)</span></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: @ONYX did this work for you or do you need more help with it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a CSS grid issue. The issue is that there's no CSS selector available to group elements by attribute value.

Also, `:last-of-type` will only find the last element of a given *element type*, not the last with a certain attribute or attribute value. Doesn't matter if you know the possible values for `data-group` or not, `:last-of-type` won't help.

Your best options here are:

1. **Change the markup** if you have control over it. Group each year with something like `<div class="year-group"> ... </div>`, and add a border to `.year-group`
2. **Use javascript to change the markup or add classnames** if you don't have direct control over the HTML markup. Iterate through the child nodes of `.grid`, and either wrap the grouped years in a containing element as above, or do something like adding a `has-bottom-border` classname to the last `div` for each year.